# Using the Field Calculator in a Domain field

Tags: arcgis-10.0, field-calculator, attribute-table, domains

I have a coded domain field with 10 dropdown options.  Possible choices include integers and text.

I need to change a selection of 250 features (which have differing values) to the same value.  This value is one of the dropdown values.

When I use the field calculator (field="value") I get an error.  The calculated value is invalid.....

Anyone know how to change multiple values within a coded domain field?

[image]

Comment: Are you calcing in the actual string value or the coded value? So if for example, 1 = "foo", I'm thinking you are needing to calc in the 1, and not "foo".

Answer (score 2):

It will depend somewhat on the type of field and domain you are using.
Assuming you are using the defaults, integer, and coded value.
you want the syntax in the field calculator to be (selectedrowsinmydomainfield) = newcodedvalue 
in the example...
[image: Pic1]
nom_size is the domain with 1 = 1"
If I want to change all selected values to 1".
I use the syntax in the middle ( [nom_size] = 1
If you are using text field with a text domain.

**EDIT:**
Ok since you are using a text domain and your codes all match your descriptions.
If you want to change all selected rows to be BETH.
[ZONE_] = "BETH"

Comment: Possible choices include integers and text.

Comment: you want to match that (the domain type) to the field type you are applying it to. Are you using text or int?  the benefit to text (there are drawbacks) is that you can make the code exactly the same as the description (what displays in attribute).

Comment: text. I added an image which might make things more clear.

Comment: re: EDIT, yes that is what I have been trying.  But I'm getting the error "The calculated value is invalid....."

Comment: (field="value")  is incorrect. you need the field name in braces and the value in double quotes. The parenth can be there if your field name is in braces (but not required)

Comment: When I use [ZONE_] = "CH10"  (ch10 is one of the choices) I get all zeros.

Comment: is that a shapefile, filegdb, ent gdb or pgdb?

Comment: hmm, i need to think about what to ask next.

Comment: personal geodatabase feature class

Comment: I see the problem. you aren't caclulating form another field. Just put "CH10" in the calculator. no field name needed. be sure you only have selected items or you will overwrite all values.

Comment: holy cow that worked.  I tried that before, but I think I was still inside of an edit session - and that may have messed it up?  ur tha man Brad!