# Using update cursor on a field with a domain

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator, domains

I have been replacing field calculations with python update cursors in many of my work flows and today I ran into a problem.  The fields being updated have an attribute domain.  so now, when I "calculate" the field based on the domain value, the field is not populated with the desired description.  Instead it is populated with the value used in the calculation.  Please see the portion of code for the update cursor.

```
# Get linear units
(path, name) = os.path.split(featureClass)
spatial_ref = arcpy.Describe(path).spatialReference
units = spatial_ref.linearUnitName
if units == "Meter":
    lengthUOM = "Metre"

# Calculate feature class fields
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(featureClass)
for row in rows:
    length = row.getValue("Shape_Length")
    row.setValue("featureLength", length)
    row.setValue("UnitOfMeasure", lengthUOM) #this field has a domain
    rows.updateRow(row)
del row, rows
```

When I use field calculator (in an edit session) and set the value to "Metre" the field will populate with the description from the domain (what I would like).  The above code, however, sets values in the field to "Metre" instead of the description.  I have read [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54767/using-the-field-calculator-in-a-domain-field), but it does not address update cursors.

Has anyone had any success with update cursors on fields with domains?  If so, could you give me some insight into where lies my mistake?  Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to get the coded value for `Metre` and calculate that coded value into the field, is that correct?

I've handled this with a dictionary before, but I created the coded-value domain myself with a dictionary (`timezones` below), so I already know the `key: value` pairs. So the trick is to, for a given value in the dict, get the key:

```
def get_timezone_key(timezone_val):
    """Get key value for a given timezone text value"""
    timezones = {1: "US/Alaska", 2: "US/Central", 3: "US/Eastern",
                 4: "US/Hawaii", 5: "US/Pacific"}
    # Get the subtype code from dict based on input def timezone user selected
    timezone_key = timezones.keys()[timezones.values().index(timezone_val)]
    return timezone_key

print get_timezone_key("US/Central") # gives 2
```

Please clarify if this is not what you are needing to accomplish.

Comment: thank you for the response. I was actually trying something similar to your response.  However, I just found an error in my code.  A key of "Metre" does not return the right value because the key value is a non-capitalized "metre" string.  Other than that, using the correct key, as you suggest, in an update cursor works perfectly.